# z-index on div and div:after are not working for my ul of tabs

Tags: html, css, angular

I understand that my parent-child relationship is what is hindering my z-index from working properly. But of the [solutions I have seen](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/), I am not able to fix without losing the hierarchy needed for my future development (The `active` class functionality, which is not yet implemented).

---

### Background Info:

I'm making a *tabs* component, and **my goal** is mirror this design (note the *slanted tab ends*):

> [image]

Here's what I was able to do:

> [image: 3]
> The only issue with this is that this code is using `float: right;` for the `li` elements instead of what I want `float: left;`.
> So because of that ***my tabs are ordered 4-1*** instead of the ***proper order*** of 1-4.

When I do use `float: left;`, this issue comes up where my divs for the *slanted tab ends* are hidden behind the `li` elements:

> [image]
> Only the last tab's slanted div is left visible, as it is the only one not blocked.

---

### Here's the Code:

```css
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    // overflow: hidden;
    clip-path: inset(0 -100vw 0 0);
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.tabs>li.active {
    // z-index: 2;
    float: left; // text-align:right; 
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 56px;
    background: lightblue;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    max-width: 222px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #10172E;
}

.tab-slice.active:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 10%; //40px
    height: 100%;
    top: 36px;
    right: 1px;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 54.5px solid lightblue;
    z-index: 3;

}

ul.tabs>li {
    float: left; 
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 56px;
    background: darkblue;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    max-width: 222px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #10172E;
}

ul.tabs>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $alis-white;
}

.tab-slice {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; //relative;
    width: .5%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -20px;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 56px solid #10172E;
    z-index: 4;
}

.tab-slice:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 10%; //40px
    height: 100%;
    top: 36px;
    right: 1px;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 54.5px solid darkblue;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
    <div class="flight-search "><a (click)="openSearch"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></a></div>
    <ul class="tabs">
    
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 1</a>
            <div class="tab-slice "></div>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a>
            <div class="tab-slice active"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 3</a>
            <div class="tab-slice"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 4</a>
            <div class="tab-slice"></div>
        </li>
        
    </ul>

</div>
```

The second to last option proposed in [that article](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/), almost works. but winds up looking like this:

> [image]
> I did this by commenting out the position attribute.

```
ul.tabs>li {
    // position: relative;
}
```

## How do I fix this layering issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can fix it, the core solution is to reverse the elements when you add them in html. Then you can use the flex property `flex-direction: row-reverse;` so that the pseudo elements always come on the top!

Was not able to find a solution for the border thing for the pseudo element!

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  clip-path: inset(0 -100vw 0 0);
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs>li.active {
  // z-index: 2;
  float: left; // text-align:right; 
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  height: 56px;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  max-width: 222px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.tabs>li {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  height: 56px;
  background: darkblue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  max-width: 222px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #10172E;
  border-right:1px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $alis-white;
}

ul.tabs>li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%; 
  height: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(100% - 1px);
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 56px solid darkblue;
}

li.active:after {
  border-right: 18px solid transparent !important;
  border-bottom: 56px solid lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
  <div class="flight-search ">
    <a (click)="openSearch">
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 1</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Using flex-direction is working! The issue with the border is it's the div before the div:after, probably. I think I can add that style.